# Onclick on image that is created in a javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick, drawing

Hiho,
I prepared a [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/VkUwQ/).

As in my example I'm using the drawImage function to draw images to a game, because I don't want to include them all in HTML ... However, my problem is, I can't find any possibility to give those "own created" images an onclick function. I thought the object "Image" (var someImage = new Image();) was comparable to the HTML `<img>` or `<input type="image">`, but no matter how hard I try, I can't make it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given the click event to the canvas context and not the canvas, change it to:

```
myCanvas.onclick = function()
```

As for making the individual images clickable (if you draw more than one), you can always keep an array of the clickable areas and the links they should go to that correspond to the images, then add a loop to the canvas click to check that the mouse co-ords match up to on of the areas in the array.

Example : [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/53pxN/7/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm  always making faults on my snippets :D I updated `myCanvas.onclick = function() { ... }` to `someImage.onclick = function() { ... }`. I was thinking about your solution but I wanted to make it easier with an onclick function, I bet there is a possibility :D

Comment: Unfortunately not, the browser just counts the canvas as one solid object, you need to keep track of the clickable areas yourself through Javascript

Comment: @HerraE if James answered your question you should upvote and accept the answer.